# How to open my app after the user turns off the standard android alarm clock?

Tags: android, android-intent, event-listener

I would like to know if it's possible to open my app right after the user is **deactivating** the alarm clock. I've read about the AlarmManager but until now I didn't find a satisfying solution to this problem.
Does anybody already have experiences on that issue?
Maybe it's working via eventlistener?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to create your own alarm app to get this functionality.  you cannot do it with other apps. so you cannot open your app if alarm is set in some other app including stock alarm app.

you can use [intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) to open some activity after alarm goes off in your app. you can use code below.

```
Intent newAppIntent;
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
newAppIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("Name of app. you want to launch");
newAppIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(newAppIntent);
```